# kubuntu 10.04.1 Installer crash please help

Tags: kubuntu

The installer got crashed while installing kubuntu 10.04.1. Any solution? Below is the pic of it.

[image]

Comment: serverfault.com?

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is restart the installation from the beginning.

First, you could also try to look at the log files /var/log/syslogd and /var/log/partman. You would have to do this by booting a linux cd and mounting the harddrive.